# HTML showing twice the same value when there is two values(flask app)

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

## **What I'm trying:**

> Making a table in html, Flask Python, SQLite3 Database that displays every user in the SQLite3 Database.

## What I'm experiencing:

> HTML is showing twice the same user.

## Python code:

```py
@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    db = sqlite3.connect("users.db", check_same_thread=False)
    c = db.cursor()
    if 'token' in session:
        try:
            token = session['token']
            c.execute("SELECT admin FROM users WHERE token=?", (token,))
            result = c.fetchone()
            if result[0] == "yes":
                # Fetch all the users from the database
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
                users = c.fetchall()
                print(users)
                db.commit()
                db.close()
                return render_template("foradmins.html", users=users)
        except TypeError as e:
                print(e)
                return render_template("foradmins.html",users=[])
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

## HTML code:

```html
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>Token</th>
                    <th>admin?</th>
                    <th>Ban</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for user in users %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ user[0] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user[1] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user[2] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user[3] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user[4] }}</td>
                    {% if isadmin=='yes' %}
                    <td>{{ isadmin }}</td>
                    {% elseif isadmin=='no'%}
                    <td>{{ isadmin }} <button onclick="addadmin('{{ user[4] }}')">Add admin</button></td>
                    {% endif %}    
                    <td><button onclick="banUser('{{ user[4] }}')">Ban</button></td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

## Traceback:

> No traceback. Only the HTML showing twice the same user.

## Note:

> in the HTML code, `banUser()` and `addadmin()` Are two Functions that are defined in the Rest of HTML code.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you mean by "HTML showing twice the same value when there is two values"?

Comment: @JonSG I made a table in HTML (like for admin pages) that shows EVERY user in the database(every row), but it's displaying the same user twice !

Comment: odd, the code looks ok to me.

Comment: So, Is there any suggestion that could Help me to fix my issue?

Comment: When you `print(users)` do you see only the correct number of users?

Comment: Your route should have a `return` at every branch. Otherwise the response may never be sent and the client's request will time out. Beyond that, this needs a [mcve]. Like Jon, I can't run the code to reproduce the problem, and there's nothing obvious here that would render two users.

Comment: @JonSG, it's not printing anything.

Comment: @ggorlen, Sorry I forgot to paste the else statement. I updated the code with the statement.

Comment: It's still possible to get through the code without sending a response: `if result[0] == "yes":` is false, then what? Anyway, this is beside the point somewhat--we can't reproduce the double user issue.

Comment: Technically there is still a path that would return an implicit `None`.. the other side of `if result[0] == "yes":`. The print() would/should have written stuff to your python console not the web page. Do you see nothing in the console?  That would be unexpected (by me)

Comment: @ggorlen, Maybe you didn't understand What I'm trying to do. I'm trying to show in the html page a table that contains EVERY user. But instead of showing every user, it's showing one user(the first one in the row exactly), Maybe there is a problem in the HTML. Maybe it's because I typed `{{ user[0] }}` it's showing always the first row.

Comment: @JonSG well, yeah. It's not printing anything.

Comment: @pydal1 I think I understand what you're trying to do, but your code looks fine to me. Your loop is `{% for user in users %}` so `user[0]` refers to the user's id of the current now, not to `users[0]`, the first user. When I ask for a [mcve], it means that your code looks 100% fine to me and shows zero indication of the problem you're claiming to be occurring. So more details are necessary.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. So where can the issue be if it's not there? I tried to check everything but it seems not working.

Comment: I don't know where the issue could be. If I did, you can be sure I'd tell you! Without a complete, runnable example, all I can do is guess. Jon's advice to `print(users)` is a good idea: you can verify that the users you're about to render are correct. If they're incorrect, then the problem is duplicate data in your database rather than a bug in your template as you expect. You claim `print(users)` returns nothing, but that seems impossible since clearly some users are showing up in your template, just not the right ones. I would take the time to figure out what's going on with `print(users)`.

Comment: I'm trying to do that, But it's not printing anything.

Comment: @ggorlen Alright, users did print, I made some changes to do that. here's what it did print:
`[(1, 'test@gmail.com', 'SIDAL', 'Sidal1234!', '5cc4f6421a15465d13b412c9cbfea502', 'yes'), (2, 'teestddd@gmail.com', 'ssss', 'ssss', 'b701142e3ae2a3cdd82350409aee9efc', 'no')]`

Comment: OK, thanks. And you're seeing which information duplicated? `test@gmail.com` and user id 1 shows up twice? Is it possible that you haven't saved your template, or that you're pointing to a different file than you think? If you run jinja with your template on that structure, there should be no problem.